# Broken message runtime dependencies

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I accidentally deleted something out of my apt/sources.list and I didn't see the name before it got deleted.

Now whenever I try to use apt-get install I get this message:

> The following packages have unmet
> dependencies:
> ros-hydro-message-runtime : Depends:
> ros-hydro-cpp-common but it is not
> going to be installed
> Depends: ros-hydro-roscpp-serialization but it
> is not going to be installed
> Depends: ros-hydro-roscpp-traits but it is not
> going to be installed
> Depends: ros-hydro-rostime but it is not going
> to be installed E: Error,
> pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated
> breaks, this may be caused by held
> packages.

How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186544/broken-message-runtime-dependencies/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used `sudo apt-get purge ros-hydro-message-runtime` and then `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full` and it seems to have worked.

---

Originally posted by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) with karma: 255 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0